# Complex gloove animation

Tags: cloth-simulation, shrinkwrap

I got to create a glove simulation, which is kinda hard to explain, but i give it a try, when you look at the below picture imagine your standing on the front of it, and those hands point to you, and you put your hand in (to get to the box with overpressure), the glove has to use cloth collision and some shrink wrap (the hand). how would one do this, i tried it with cloth sim and shrink wrap; but shrink wrap is way to strong (disables cloth self collision).
One might wonder about shapekeys but (invert model over length axis) but it doesnt look realistic and wont reflect movement of the working hands in lab.

[image]